# Help interpret cancellation charges for hotel booking

Tags: bookings, hotels, airbnb

[image: Timeline of booking and cancellation charges]

The above image is a screenshot of the cancellation and refund rules for a hotel booked through airbnb.com. It mentions "**Strict: Free cancellation for 48 hours**". Does that imply that 48 hours after the booking, there will be no refund, or does it mean that 48 hours before the check-in, there will be no refund?

Comment: I don't see how this is at all confusing: the timeline makes it 100% obviously clear that the 48 hours is counted from the reservation confirmation date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means you can cancel the booking within 48 hours of making it and not be charged, if your checkin date is at least 14 days away.

Cancelling 48 hours after booking (but more than 7 days before the checkin date) you’d be charged 50% of the cost (plus the service fee).

Cancelling anytime 7 days or less before the checkin date, you’d receive no refund.

Comment: We have made booking on 14 March, 2019 and our check-in date is 22nd April, 2019? So, if we cancel on 30 March, 2019 will we receive full refund?

Comment: No, to get a full refund you’d need to cancel by 16 March (ie within 48 hours of booking). If you cancel on 30 March you’ll receive 50% refund less service fees.

Comment: The only ambiguity appears to be whether the 14 days are counted from the date of reservation or the date of cancellation.

Comment: @MSalter I believe it’s counted backwards in hours from the date & time of the reservation checkin - see the screenshot in the OP’s question. Reservation confirmed at 1pm, the subsequent cut-offs also occur at 1pm. It’s quite clear in the screenshot that the OP can cancel up to 1pm on 15 April, after that they would not get a refund.